# Animating Preset Extent in Bar Chart dc.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, bar-chart, dc.js

I created a bar chart with use of Dimensional Charting library(dc.js).

I am trying to set a 4 year filter:

```
filter = dc.filters.RangedFilter(new Date(start,1, 1), new Date(end, 12, 1));
```

where `end` will always be 4 years ahead of `start`, and render this extent/filter every 5 seconds.

For example: `start= 2000` and `end= 2004` would be my starting var dates.

I want dc to render that extent and then delay 5 seconds and advance the extent 4 years till my boolean variable is false. The boolean variable is connected to a play button I have created and manipulating with JQuery.

Is there any way to do the delay? I have tried.

```
setTimeout(function(){}, xms)
```

but unfortunately I am running this within a loop and by the time loop is done I skip from the start to the very end.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by running this within a loop. Why not set the timeout outside the loop? You certainly only want to set it once.

Comment: Maybe you should show more of your code? Sounds kind of like you want to increment the year counter when the timeout happens, and then set a new timeout, but it's hard for me to tell without seeing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, It was hard to explain, but I set the SetInterval method outside my while condition and it now seems to be working fine. Thank You for the help Gordon. Sometimes thoughts are convoluted and the answer is simple as calling the code and switching over to setInterval method.